# Filter EVERY string in an array that contains a specific value

Tags: javascript

I've got an array:

```
var stringOne = ["big dog","small dog", "big cat", "small cat"]
```

And I want to filter out every string that **contains** "dog".

Of course the function of:

```
var stringTwo = stringOne.filter((e) => e !== "dog")
```

doesn't work as there is no string of exactly "dog", but I'm curious if there's a built in function to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `String.prototype.includes`:

```js
var stringOne = ["big dog", "small dog", "big cat", "small cat"]

const filterByWord = (arr, word = "") => {
  return arr.filter(s => {
    return s.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(word.toLocaleLowerCase());
  });
}
console.log(filterByWord(stringOne, "dog"));
```

Comment: How well does this handle case sensitivity?

Comment: @RichardBarker out of the box it won't but it easily can. I have more details in my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63943051/64669)

Comment: @RichardBarker Edited to handle case sensitive query.

Answer (score 3):

[`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is the simplest way but it is limited to the exact string you're searching for. I.e.:

```js
"small dog".includes("dog") #=> true
"Big Dog".includes("dog")  #=> false
```

Typically software developers will lowercase strings ([`String#toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)) before doing comparisons to normalize them.

```js
"Big Dog".toLowerCase().includes("dog")  #=> true
```

Another incredibly useful but also complicated tool you should be aware of are [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (regex or regexp for short). These allow you to use a special syntax to determine if a given string matches the conditions you've specified. I think a regexp is overkill for this use case but they have features that sidestep the casing problem.

```js
regexp = /dog/i #=> match the case insensitive sequence of letters "dog"
regexp.test("small dog") #=> true
regexp.test("Big Dog")   #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

**source** [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

**source** [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

```js
function myFunction(reg) {
    var stringOne = ["big dog","small Dog", "big cat", "small cat"];
  var dogs = stringOne.filter(function(val){
      if(val.toLowerCase().match(reg)){
        return val;
    }
  });
  console.log(dogs)
}
var reg = /dog/g;
 myFunction(reg);
```